# How to change the title of the button after selecting the row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a button in one class and table view in another class.

I want that, when I select table view row the title of button is changed and show the text of selected row on button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write the code for that in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method.

```
[yourButtonName setTitle:@"The Text To be displayed." forState:UIControlStateNormal"];
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how are your two classes related.

If class A has defined an instance of class B... You can do `[b.button setTitle:@"whateertitle"]`;

Or you need to do an optional protocol and delegate method... In either case, call the method from `DidSelectRowAtIndexPath`: method from A class in my example.